# Этимология слова "ворочаться"

Tags: этимология

Откуда произошло слово "Ворочаться"? Уж не от слова ли вор??

Answer (score 4):

Оттуда же, откуда "вращаться", "поворачиваться".

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: русск.-церк.-слав. вращати, укр. вороча́ти, белор. вороча́ць, болг. вра́щам

Answer (score 0):

Ворота - из той же песни. Корень один.